# Postgres table sync between different schemas

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have table A in schema A and table B in schema B with same structure in the same database. Whenever a DML change happens in table A, I need the same in table B. For now, I am using triggers to do the same. Is there any better alternative than using triggers for this scenario?

As the tables belong to different microservices, I need one of the tables with data unmodified even if the other table is dropped.

Comment: Triggers seems to me to be the best approach for that. But wouldn't it be easier to use the same table and just prevent it from being dropped?

Comment: Both tables will have common columns but one of the tables will have additional columns that are not supposed to be accessed by the other user. That's why two different tables.

Comment: @Manoharan You can grant select privileges on only certain columns to one of the users.